# read/write cache to 1TB file - proxy/view on buffers

Tags: java, caching, io, buffer

I would like to have an object that emulates (in pure Java) **memory mapping of file bigger than entire virtual memory** (measured in Tera bytes).

```
/** interface to memory-mapped file emulator that can read/write to mapped file
 * and return multiple views on it. */
public interface FileView {

    /** returns single byte of mapped file at position (long index) */
    byte getByte (long pos);

    /** sets single byte of mapped file at position (long index) to a value */
    void setByte (long pos, byte value);

    /** returns ByteBuffer-like class exposing bytes of mapped file
     * in specified range (from - to, long indices).
     * Length of that buffer can be arbitrary limited (perhaps to 50MB) */
    XxxByteBuffer getBuffer (long from, long to);

    /** register new range of bytes that needs to be listened
     * and in case of change, listener should get informed.
     * RangeChangedListener takes two arguments in constructor: long from, long to */
    void addRangeChangedListener(RangeChangedListener l);
}
```

My questions (6) are below under big header and here goes context informations.

**Each returned instance of ByteBufer-like class should stay consistent (have the same contents in regions that overlap) with each other.** So in case one of the buffers changes the others should change appropriately if they overlaps. And additionally **if the change occurs in listened region, the listener should be informed** (for buffers, synchronizing and listening ought to be a single mechanism. For proxy views - there is no problem on synchronizing but listener problem remains). This synchronisation doesn't have to be "super hi performance" but it should be reliable. I presume there will be many overlapping buffers but not many modifications.
I assume most of the time I will be getting little buffers (let's say 2kb) out of the "FileView".

**Every individual write should be somehow stored in memory (apart from writing to buffer).** Writing directly to file is not permitted until user clicks "SAVE". Of course it can't last for long - I assume there is no need to cache more than 200MB in memory (huge blocks of changes can be cached in temp files on disk). These individual changes can be spreaded over entire mapped file. In case an adjacent positions in file were modified, the changes can be aggregated.

So FileView MUST:

1. buffer currently used data in memory.
2. store all individual changes (writes) in cache.
3. expose ByteBuffer-like objects on demand (by reading new data from
   file or get existing data from memory) and apply on them appropriate
   cached changes (if any changes exists).
4. synchronize ByteBuffer-like objects to each other when they
   overlaps.
5. discard from memory clean data (not currently used and not changed)
   (to preserve memory)
6. safely discard from memory "dirty data" when currently not in use:
   to do it it must make sure changes are stored and then discard data
   as if they were clean
7. Monitor currently used memory amount compared to maximum and in case
   of low memory - try to discard as many as possible.

There are two big performance problems:

**1. getting new data as views, not as standalone buffers**

After following calls:

```
fileView.getBuffer(0,200000000);
fileView.getBuffer(0,200000789);
```

we have two standalone copies of 200MB-chunk of data. And consecutive calls will produce next copies of the same data.
So maybe fileView should return view on existing internal buffer not a new buffer? But then - how to produce internal buffer? It will be "patchwork". fileView will create buffers internally on demand and return views on these internal buffers glued and patched somehow together. Look below - existing internal buffers are reused (patched) in fourth call:

```
fileView.getBuffer(0,2);  // {0,1,2}
fileView.getBuffer(4,5);  // {4,5}
fileView.getBuffer(8,12); // {8,9,10,11,12}
fileView.getBuffer(0,16); // {0,1,2} {3} {4,5} {6,7} {8,9,10,11,12} {13,14,15,16}
```

**2. getting rid of internal data (GC them) without destroying views**

When there is low memory, we should:

- GC unchanged buffers (as we can read them later once again from HD);
- store our changes (writes) in cache and GC modified buffers also.

This way we could totally get rid of any read data (but keep our changes (writes) in separate cache).
But...

there are buffer views returned to external components - these views has references to our internal buffers so we can't GC internal buffers. And we don't want to destroy these external views - they should stay as they are - we only want do get rid of internal data and later fill them back on demand (like proxy).

.

### I am looking for an architecturally good solution to the situation described above. And here is what exactly I need to know:

.

1. How to get new data as views not as standalone buffers?
   I want to:

   - avoid multiple standalone copies of the same data in multiple buffers, so I want views
   - after fileView.getBuffer (long from, long to); return something functionally similar to ByteBuffer
   - do not ruin performance too much compared to naked ByteBuffers
     Maybe I should return instance of brand new class implementing proxy view on internal buffers of fileView and having interface similar to bytebuffer???
2. What data structure is proper to keep track of what is loaded and what is not? Maybe TreeMap plus LinkedList of Leafs with buffers retained inside leafs?
3. How to get rid of internal data (GC) without destroying external views?
4. How to synchronize ( = guarantee to be equal) contents of returned buffers/views in overlapping regions?
   This problem disappears in case of views because every view references the same underlying structure.
5. How to efficiently store individual changes (writes) and then reapply them to newly returned buffers/views on reloading data from file? Every single change could be one byte long but it can be also several megabytes long.
6. How to efficiently map selected range of bytes to proper listener (single listener listens to changes in defined range of bytes - not in entire buffer)?

.

### For those of you who are still reading I can provide some additional details of what am I doing :)

I know next to nothing about caching and very little about buffers but...

I try to create a **hex editor with scripting engine (DSL) inside and with GUI-to-data binding**. The purpose is data analysis and recovery.
My language of choice is Java + Groovy. Some parts of project are in advanced stage now and they are based on ByteBuffers, CharBuffers etc.

I have following **business constraints** for my application:

1. the app can open extremely large files (backup files of HD) - let's say 1-2TB
   (Tera Bytes);
2. user can see opened file, scroll it and modify (like in any hex
   editor);
3. scripting engine has random access to the file and can process it
   (read/write/bind);
4. data can be bound to GUI by script, i.e. bytes 100000045 through
   100000048 could be treated as INTEGER and displayed in JTextField.
   When these bytes changes - JTextField changes too. When someone
   changes text field - then underlying data (in file) changes.
5. file should stay intact until we click save.

Script will be run strictly in context of opened file and its major task is (a) read and write to that file (b) print information about that file (c) bind regions of file to fields in GUI.

I suspect there will be two kind of needs (script types but somewhat fuzzy):

**ABSOLUTE SCRIPT**. Scripts that potentially need entire file and absolute addressing - they could look for something i.e. find partition table and check partitions. I don't think they will process file sequentially (like streams). Instead they will supposedly need access to several places scattered over entire file but these places won't be large - I suspect about 50MB.

**RELATIVE SCRIPT**. Scripts that works generally locally - they could interpret some bytes ((pointed by user directly with mouse or by other script)) as a record of data that has known layout and dynamically create fields in GUI and bind data to that fields.

There are plethora of file types that have partially static layout and some disc data structures too. For example NTFS boot sector has static layout near its start:

```
char[8] - "File system ID"
uint16 - "Bytes per sector"
uint8 - "Sectors per cluster"
uint16 - "Reserved sectors"
...
```

By 'static' I mean that you can read bytes from file to byte buffer and then blindly interpret first 8 bytes as characters describing file system id then next two bytes as unsigned int indicating bytes per sector value and so on.
So you can create text fields, describe them with labels and display data inside.